# Overwriting styled component 3 times?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using react-bootstrap and styled components on a project and am having issues with extending styles [link to docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles)

For example, im importing and overriding a bootstrap button component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

export const PrimaryButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.purple300};
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
`;
```

this is a good start, however, I want to override this in several locations as well, so something like:

```
import {Button} from './button.style'

const AuthButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: red;
`;
 ....
 <AuthButton type='submit'>Sign In</AuthButton>
```

`AuthButton` should have 3 classes (bootstrap, the first styled component, and then the second), but I'm seeing everything except the AuthButton styles/class. I don't see the `background-color: red;` anywhere in the DOM. I've tried increasing specificity using `&&&` and still nothing.

Is this a limitation with styled components or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. Please try to get a working example of this problem in https://codesandbox.io or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this. It was due to not having a className prop in my Button component: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component

EDIT: Since the mods are absolutely horrendous on SO, I will add an example:

```
function MyComponent({className}) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need pass `className` as a props to your component